# How to best integrate Flex and Django?

Tags: django, apache-flex, ria

I'm building a site with a Flex frontend and Django backend.

The problem I'm facing is that it's tedious to write a CRUD frontend for every model.

I've checked out [django-rest-interface](http://code.google.com/p/django-rest-interface/) but it is not obvious on how to do anything other than read/GET (i.e. create/POST, update/PUT, delete/DELETE) and couldn't find any related examples.

The usual answer I get on asking this question is "Use AMF" but what I am trying to learn is how to actually do the interfacing, not the protocol format.

So, bottom line, what are the best practices and simplest ways to integrate Flex and Django?

Answer (score 4):

@Matt Briggs, The DjangoAMF tutorial wasn't clear enough and I was unable to make headway there.

I've finally gotten hold of [how to use PyAMF](http://www.pyamf.org/wiki/DjangoHowto) and so far, so good.

Answer (score 1):

Asked a buddy who is doing just that, he said he uses the [DjangoAMF](http://djangoamf.sourceforge.jp/index.php?UserManual_en) library